# What is the proper location for user defined environment variables?

Tags: 18.04, environment-variables

What is the proper location for user defined environment variables in Ubuntu?

My first guess would be `~/.profile`. Ubuntu already creates that file which conditionally sources `~/.bashrc` and does some other things. That can't be it.

My second guess would be `~/.bashrc`. Ubuntu also creates that and it contains even more than `~/.profile`.

Comment: I put my aliases, functions and variables in `~/.bashrc`